# Add to a hrefs of certain class using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

This is my code

```js
function pagechangefl() {
  var list1 = document.getElementsByClassName("fl");
  for (var k = 0; k < list1.length; k++) {
    var str1 = list1[k].href;
    var str2 = "&num=100";
    if (!(str1.endsWith("&num=100"))) {
      list1[k].href = str1 + str2;
    }
  }
}

function pagechangepn() {
  var list2 = document.getElementsByClassName("pn");
  for (var i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
    var str3 = list2[i].href;
    var str4 = "&num=100";
    if (!(str3.endsWith("&num=100"))) {
      list2[i].href = str3 + str4;
    }
  }
}

var t1 = setInterval(pagechangefl, 1000);
var t2 = setInterval(pagechangepn, 1000);
```

The problem of the current code is that I don't want to use a timer I want these functions to run everytime the page is updated with # links example. Even with a timer the pagechangefl function doesn't add the addition for some reason.

https://www.google.com/search?q=test&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:0000&start=000&tbm=bks&num=100

vs

https://www.google.com/search?q=test&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:0000&start=000&tbm=bks&num=100#q=test&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:0000&tbm=bks&start=100&num=100

Comment: What does "updated with # links example" mean? It's really not clear to me what you are desiring to have happen, or at least when you are desiring to have it happen (when it's not).

Comment: You appear to be wanting to add `&num=100` to Google search links. Are you aware that you can just set the Google search settings to always show you 100 results by default? Thus, not needing to have that as part of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to come up with the current architecture from the code.

But you can call these two functions once the function for updating the page is triggered.

Assuming there is a function which will trigger update

```
function updatePage(){
 // Rest of code
 // on update complete call the other two function
 pagechangefl()
 pagechangepn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.fn[href], .pn[href]')
        .forEach(function(node){
            var url = new URL(node.href), 
                hash = new URLSearchParams(url.hash.replace(/^#/, ""));

            hash.searchParams.set('num', 100);
            url.hash = hash;
            node.href = url;
        });
});
```